# Schedule a repeating event in Python

Tags: python, scheduler

I am writing a script running as daemon process. Every 12 hours, it runs some job.

Is that a good practice to do the following code? I'm using Python 2.7

```
import sched

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
scheduler.enter(0, 1, update, ())

while True:
    scheduler.run()
    scheduler.enter(12*60*60, 1, update, ())
```

Is there any other better option?

Comment: call your program from cron - way way way better

Comment: Is the every-12-hours-job the **only** thing your daemon does? If so, consider cron, as others say. But if your daemon is also a network server, or otherwise must be running, perhaps cron isn't your best choice.

Comment: I actually would love to use cron job for this. But I have some contraints:
1. the job "update" has to be ran by root. 2. I do not have permission to start my cron job as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessarily bad practice but it means that there's a python instance consuming resources 24/7. You also run the risk of something interrupting (stopping) your program and it being ineffective.

Perhaps you might [investigate the cron service](http://artoflinux.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/cron-jobs-tutorial-for-beginners.html)? Adding this process to your crontab would be much more robust.

Comment: cron is absolutely a better idea. but 1. the job "update" has to be ran by root. 2. I do not have permission to start my cron job as root.

Comment: @cli130 that's surprising: how do you get your python script to run as root?

Comment: Encouraging cronservices is a good option, but can be misleading especially when some recurring tasks need to remain in the workflow of the application. It's best to handle your interruptions instead of just writing a cron and saying "not necessarily bad practice" that rubbed me the wrong way